# Drilling through in ssas to a dimension attribute that has hierarchy disabled

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008, drillthrough

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, developing using BIDS.
I have a very large cube, with many dimensions, and I am building a drill through action.
The requirement is for a very broad drill through, which includes many fields that are in the fact table (and are not used in the cube, except for in drill through), and also many dimensions have attributes that are not hierarchy enabled such as textual info.

I have created the dimensions, and added all the attributes required for the drill through as dimension attributes (I added a fact dimension for the fields in the fact table), and defined all the attributes that are used for drill through as AttributeHierarchyEnabled = "false".

Yet, when I add a drill through action, only attributes that are Hierarchy enabled appear in the drop down while attributes having hierarchy disabled fail the drill through action.

I wish to avoid all unnecessary hierarchies as my processing time is getting extremely long, yet the drill through requirement is rigid.

Please help me over adding an attribute that has hierarchy disabled to drill through?

Thank you.